# C++ Template type check std::is_same not working?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Giving the following code:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
static void parse(T & result)
{
    if (std::is_same<T, struct Foo>::value)
    {
        result.fooValue = 123;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, struct Bar>::value)
    {
        result.barValue = 456;
    }
}

struct Foo { int fooValue; };
struct Bar { int barValue; };

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    parse(foo);

    Bar bar;
    parse(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

This won't compile with error message:

```
error C2039: 'barValue': is not a member of 'Foo'
error C2039: 'fooValue': is not a member of 'Bar'
```

What am I doing wrong? can someone please explain to me why when after I pass `foo` into `parse` and passing `bar` it thinks that it's `foo` and therefore throwing compiler errors. What's the common sense behind this? or in other words, what's the proper why of checking the template type.

Note that I already know about template specialization and instantiation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (false) { /* code that produces a type error */ }` is still a type error in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When template is instantiated, both branches need to be compiled. Obviously, one of them can't - the specific template type has only one member, but not another.

To solve this problem, you would either need `constexpr if` from C++17, or, with previous versions, use tag dispatch or SFINAE.

Comment: There is an additional problem, that they are using is::same with a `struct Foo` which is a different type, not the Foo type defined below, so even with if constexpr it will compile but will not be correct.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyA! Completely forgot about these topics and you brought it up again for me. I didn't knew about the `if constexpr` feature, that's brilliant and saves tons of headache!